# Why is iron an essential part of iron fertilization and carbon sink?

Tags: climate, geoengineering, plant

I just started researching iron fertilization, which is the induction of carbon sinks in the atmosphere through depositing iron in large areas, specifically the ocean. Why do most of the studies regarding carbon sinks revolve around iron, and not other various nutrients like nitrogen and phosphorous that exist?

I know that iron is an important mineral for photosynthesis, but so is nitrogen. Is there any specific properties about iron that makes it more important in the process of phytoplankton growth?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's largely because iron is scarce in seawater. It is what is known as a limiting factor -- certain physiological processes can't occur in the absence of iron, so even if nutrients such as nitrogen and phosphorous are plentiful many organisms cannot metabolize them.

Here's one popular-science article on this theme: [The Complicated Role of Iron in Ocean Health and Climate Change](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/complicated-role-iron-ocean-health-and-climate-change-180973893/)
And a 2017 scientific paper in *Nature* that explores a particular case: [Nutrient co-limitation at the boundary of an oceanic gyre](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature24063)

> Our results suggest that nitrogen–iron co-limitation is pervasive in
> the ocean, with other micronutrients also approaching co-deficiency.
> Such multi-nutrient limitations potentially increase phytoplankton
> community diversity.